# checkbox with desired value are not being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm building a form for business opening hours that looks like this:

[image: opening times picture]

when the closed checkbox is checked it disables the inputs.
the data is added and retrieved from the database just fine, the problem comes when i want to edit the times, the boxes are not checked and default values of 00:00 are shown.

I have

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value=""]').prop("checked",true);
```

in my JS file

my html checkboxes are like so:

```
<input id="wednesday_closed" name="wednesday_closed" type="checkbox" value="">
```

Some have values like 12:00 (time), but some have "" (no value) as that is how it is saved in the DB for closed.
I want to check all of the ones with no value (i.e. they are closed).

I've tried the above code but also tried seeing if it ticks check boxes with values, e.g.

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value="00:00"]').prop("checked",true);
```

and it does not check any of them either. Other Javascript is working fine.

I have also tried numerous other solutions to similar problems on this board and I have not been able to figure it out, so obviously I am missing something...

I hope this makes sense. Thank you so much to anyone who read this & tries to help

Comment: How are you creating/adding the elements from the database results? **Also** How are you editing/updating the stored data? Are you using a form to post the data and reload the page or are you using `ajax` to post in the background?

Comment: My suspicion is that you are running the js code before the html has had chance to render. Are you containing it in a $(document).ready() and/or running it only once you know the HTML has had chance to render?

Comment: @NewToJS I'm using a form to post

Comment: @Stephen I have it in a $(document).ready()

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Also, why not use `ajax` to post the data in the background? It would save reloading the page and if you wish to confirm the changes you can have the server reply with the new results to check those match.

Comment: @Stephen that comment made me think, and I've just tried a simple alert popup with document ready and it does not work. I have the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in my code though and other javascript works so I'm even more confused as to what is wrong

Comment: @thx4help Open your browser console and check for errors. If you see any please edit your question and include the message(s) you have. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you! The console said $ was undefined and it turns out I had the jquery script tag under my other js script files. Thank you so much for your help. As to your other question, I am fairly new to ajax so am not so confident enough to do that yet, maybe one day!

Comment: @thx4help Very welcome, it is a common mistake to make. Remember, the browser console is your best friend when working with `javascript`